# How to access inner stringified JSON data using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

JSON:

```
{  
    "o-data":[  
        {  
            "entry 1":"test1",
            "entry 2":"test2",
            "entry 3":"test3",
            "entry 4":"118"
        }
    ]
}
```

C#:

```
dynamic dn = dyndata(json);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dn)
{
    //I would like to be able to get all the inner data for `o-data` like below...
    string entry1 = "";// test1
    string entry2 = "";// test2
    string entry3 = "";// test3

    //but instead I get `{[o-data, System.Object[]]}`
    string second = kvp.Value.ToString(); // gives my 'System.Object[]'
}

public dynamic dyndata(string json)
{
    dynamic dyn1 = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    try
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
        return result);
    }
    catch { return Tuple.Create(dDummy, false); }
}
```

How can I the KVP of the inner list for 'o-data'.

Currently it only loop once because of `o-data`. I would like to get the inner list of `o-data` and loop through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some castings are required:
1) cast the `kvp.Value` to `object[]` because "o-data" contains an array
2) cast the first item of this array to `IDictionary<string, object>`

```
dynamic dn = dyndata(json);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dn)
{
    var array = ((object[])kvp.Value);
    var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) array[0];
    var entry1 = dictionary["entry 1"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you... it's weird, locally your code works but i had to revert back to my code to work correctly when the site is hosted in IIS... weird weird weird! Thanks for the help. +1 and accepted.